# I'm Working on a django project where i extended the auth_user table for add the operators and this will give an error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

MY HTML CODE ===

This is my html code for adding the operator in the database

```
{% extends 'Adminside/master.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- general form elements -->
    <div class="card card-primary">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Add Operator</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <!-- form start -->
      <form role="form" action="{% url 'addoperator' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputname" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
              </div>  
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputaddress" name="address" placeholder="Enter Your Address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputnumber" name="number" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
          </div> 

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!-- radio -->
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radioPrimary1" name="gender" value="Male" checked="">
                <label for="radioPrimary1">
                    Male
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radioPrimary2" value="Female" name="gender">
                <label for="radioPrimary2">
                    Female
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                <input type="radio" id="radioPrimary3"  disabled="">

                 Gender
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Image Upload</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="userimage" class="form-control" required>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Document Upload</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="document" class="form-control" required>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->


    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->

  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

MY VIEWS CODE =====

This is my views code for enter the data

```
def addoperator(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            opera = User.objects.create_user(
            username=request.POST['name'],
            email=request.POST['email'],
            password=request.POST['password']

        )
            s=Operator()
            s.user=opera 
            s.phonenumber=request.POST['number']
            s.gender=request.POST['gender']
            s.address=request.POST['address']
            s.picture=request.FILES['userimage']
            s.document=request.FILES['document']
            s.save()
            return render(request,'Adminside/addoperators.html')
        else:
            return render(request,'Adminside/addoperators.html')
```

MY MODELS CODE ===

```
class Operator(models.Model):
        # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,default='')
        # These fields are optional
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    phonenumber=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='operator/', blank=True)
    document = models.ImageField(upload_to='operator/', blank=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='PENDING')

    def isActive(self):
            if self.status=="ACTIVE":
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def isDisable(self):
            if self.status=="DISABLE":
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

MY ERROR WHILE WORKING ON THIS

```
OperationalError at /addoperator
table Adminside_operator has no column named user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addoperator
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
table Adminside_operator has no column named user_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:
```

This is the main error that i've been stuck on this thing and in this code model i careated the user field only but it gives an error about the user_id which i don't understand where it is comes from, any help would be appreciated ...... Thank you

Comment: Did you edit models.py after you made migrations? You may need to rerun `python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate`

Comment: yes i did that, and makemigrations is working but migrate command is not working